# AirFlow - disable dag after X consecutive fails

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I read the API reference and couldnt find anything on it, is that possible?

Comment: By `"..disable dag.."` you mean [*pausing*](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/models.py#L3243) the `DAG` or just [*timing-out*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54810074/3679900) (stop further retries)?

Comment: I mean making sure it wont be scheduled again until I manually enable it again, or maybe activate an exponential backoff.
The problem is that I have a DAG that runs every 5 minutes, so if something does wrong at night for example, I'll wake up with 100 e-mails about failed DAG

Comment: The link to pausing doesnt work but from googling it seems that what I meant is indeed pausing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no such feature that does it out-of-the-box but you can write some custom code in your DAG to get around this. For example, use PythonOperator (you can use MySQL operator if your metadata db is mysql) to get status of the last X runs for the dag. 
use `BranchPythonOperator` to see if the number is more than X, if it is then use a BashOperator to run `airflow pause dag` cli.

You can also just make this a 2-step task by adding logic of PythonOperator in BranchPythonOperator. This is just an idea, you can use a different logic.